# how to stop recyclerview automatic refresh when a new item added firebase Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

Hey I am making an app that has a feature to upload Instagram reels like videos and I setup exoplayer in recycler view but when new data is added by another user or a user uploaded a new reel the recycler view automatic refresh on another mobile and all the videos are stuck please help here is my code

```
public class NotificationFragemt extends Fragment implements Player.EventListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<ModelVideos> videosList;
    int currentPage=-1;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    boolean is_user_stop_video=false;
    VideoAdapter videoAdapter;
    private CardView plus_card;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_fragemt, container, false);
//        getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getActivity().getColor(R.color.black));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.videorecyclerview);
        videosList = new ArrayList<>();
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

        plus_card = view.findViewById(R.id.plus_card);

        plus_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Upload_reels.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });





//        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true);
//        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
//        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        SnapHelper snapHelper =  new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        Collections.shuffle(videosList);

         videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(getActivity(),videosList);
        loadpost();




        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            }
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                //here we find the current item number
                final int scrollOffset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
                final int height = recyclerView.getHeight();
                int page_no=scrollOffset / height;
                if(page_no!=currentPage ){
                    currentPage=page_no;
                    Release_Previous_Player();
                    Set_Player(currentPage);

                }
            }
        });





        return view;



    }

    SimpleExoPlayer privious_player;
    public void Release_Previous_Player(){
        if(privious_player!=null) {
            privious_player.removeListener(this);
            privious_player.release();
        }
    }

    private void loadpost() {

        DatabaseReference ref;

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TravelReels");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                videosList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    ModelVideos modelPost = ds.getValue(ModelVideos.class);



                    videosList.add(modelPost);

                    Collections.reverse(videosList);
                    Collections.shuffle(videosList);



















                }


                setAdapter();







            }



            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });








    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        if (!videoAdapter.hasObservers()) {
            videoAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);



    }

    public boolean is_fragment_exits(){
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public void Set_Player(int currentPage){

        try {
            LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                    .setAllocator(new DefaultAllocator(true, 16))
                    .setBufferDurationsMs(1 * 1024, 1 * 1024, 500, 1024)
                    .setTargetBufferBytes(-1)
                    .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true)
                    .createDefaultLoadControl();


            DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
            final SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), trackSelector, loadControl);

            DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(),
                    Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));

            Log.d("video_url"+currentPage,videosList.get(currentPage).getVideoUrl());

            MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videosList.get(currentPage).getVideoUrl()));

       /* MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(proxyUrl));

            Log.d(Variables.tag,item.video_url);
            Log.d(Variables.tag,proxyUrl);*/


            player.prepare(videoSource);

            player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
            player.addListener(this);


            View layout = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(currentPage);
            final PlayerView playerView = layout.findViewById(R.id.reels_player);
            playerView.setPlayer(player);
             player.setPlayWhenReady(is_visible_to_user);
            privious_player = player;
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }


    }

    boolean is_visible_to_user;
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        is_visible_to_user=isVisibleToUser;

        if(privious_player!=null && (isVisibleToUser && !is_user_stop_video)){
            privious_player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
        else if(privious_player!=null && !isVisibleToUser){
            privious_player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        is_visible_to_user = true;
        if((privious_player!=null && (!is_user_stop_video)) && !is_fragment_exits() ){
            privious_player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(privious_player!=null){
            privious_player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(privious_player!=null){
            privious_player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(privious_player!=null){
            privious_player.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, @Nullable Object manifest, int reason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekProcessed() {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `loadpost` function you're using `addValueEventListener` which calls `onDataChange` everytime there is a change in your `TravelReels` node.

If you don't want that it should listen to these continues changes. Only load the data once. Then you can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` which will get called only once. Read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_a_listener

But if you want to control it yourself then just add one boolean flag `shouldRefresh` make it true /false according to your needs & notify adapter only when it's true. Write you logic.